# Where do the MySQL database files reside for WAMP?

Tags: mysql, database, file

I'm just curious as I am beginning to learn PHP and MySQL, as to where the database and other files of MySQL reside on the hard drive. I have installed WAMP on a Windows XP SP2 platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Usually in the `/mysql/data` directory of your WAMP installation. You'll recognize the location because every database has a folder with the same name there.

You can change the location of the data directory using the `datadir` setting in `my.cnf`. It is often moved elsewhere to ensure the data there gets backed up regularly.

Comment: Hi got it ...was slightly different here - C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\data

Answer (score 14):

Explore variables from the output of following command:

mysql> `show variables like '%dir%'`;

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the Variable_name for where mysql keeps the databases files is: datadir

Answer (score 13):

Data directories for `mysql` database :

#### Generally,

Windows `wamp setup` : `mysql/data`
Linux (Ubuntu)       : `/var/lib/mysql`

#### Configured Location: [ `my.cnf` configures it as `datadir` ]

Linux :

```
$ cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep 'datadir'
```

Windows :

```
  Open mysql/my.cnf (search for `datadir` )
```

#### From `mysql` prompt : ( `mysql>` )  [ PREFERRED WAY ]

```
  mysql> show variable like 'datadir';
```

I suppose that covers pretty much all cases.

Comment: On my WAMP installation the command is
mysql>show variables like 'datadir';
Note the plural on variables. The singular form causes an error.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about WAMP, but if you install MySQL manually it should reside somewhere along the lines of this path:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following to find the data directory using SQL console:

```
show variables like 'datadir'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your on linux you can use:

```
sudo find / mysql | grep mysql
```

On Ubuntu it stores its database files in /var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 0):

wamp/bin/mysql/mysqlx.x.x/data