# Restoring PHPMyAdmin from Disk

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, backup

I have a windows machine that was running phpmyadmin as part of WAMP.

The windows installation broke but I have a full disk backup.

Is there a way to restore a database to a new instillation from the disk without having to do the manual export procedure (as obviously I cant do this!)

Thanks

Comment: If you install the same Version of MySQL to the same path as in the original machine, the simply replace the `data` folder and config file with the one from your disk, things will just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpMyAdmin is the wrong place to be focusing.  You will need to restore the original MYSQL tables and config.

[This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727920/where-does-the-mysql-database-files-actually-reside) gives details about where to find these files in a WAMP installation.

Comment: Thanks - makes sense - silly oversight from me - will check and report back